# Position RelativeLayout below RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[RelativeLayout in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxFjP.png)

i have  a horizontal LinearLayout in which i have a RelativeLayout and i want another RelativeLayout to be below it and likewise throughout the xml file but the Layout is appearing at the immediate right of the previous Layout

i have tried to set the top margin of the RelativeLayout to a certain random value e.g 60sp it positions below the previous RelativeLayout but when i add TextView the TextView Does Not Show up in the design view

[After adding textview to RelativeLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0zga.png)

How do i position the Layout below the previous RelativeLayout ? and also how do i add TextViews to this RelativeLayout and display them ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/calcbackground"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="SHIFT"
        android:id="@+id/shifttextiew"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="DEG"
        android:id="@+id/degtextview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shifttextiew"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shifttextiew"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="RAD"
        android:id="@+id/radtextview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/degtextview"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/degtextview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="GRAD"
        android:id="@+id/gradtextview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radtextview"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radtextview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="12345678910"
        android:id="@+id/calculationtextview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shifttextiew"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60sp">

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_below="@id/`

Comment: Layout is appearing right because your parent layout orientation is horizontal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told it to be at the right here: `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Make your `LinearLayout` vertical instead.

Answer (score 1):

I see your code you don't add any orientation on root layout.if you don't add any orientation then it will work on horizontal.Please add the below code on your root layout.Hope it will work.

```
  android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

make to seprate layout and using include layout tag place both layout according to your need

Answer (score 0):

changes required in topmost viewgroup(LinearLayout)

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

instead of

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

use orientation="vertical" property for your parent Linear layout